# Barchart not working as expect after calling setVisibleXRangeMaximum

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I just called `chartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(3)` and its works fine for the first time.
I can see first 3 bars and the horizontal scrolls are enabled.

But once we increased the bars count, and reset back to old initial bar count, the bar width is increased dramatically.

Related issue: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4506

[image: initial state][image: increased bar count][image: width broken when count reset to initial]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kazi05 [commented](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4506#issuecomment-739854076) on github:

Make `chartView.fitScreen()` before every time that you set `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(_)` will solve the issue.